# ROSJava & catkin_make run_tests

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like at present `catkin run_tests` doesn't run the `gradle test` command for ROS java projects. Is there any easy way to cause that to happen?

I'd like to be able to use this functionality in the ShadowRobot CI setup on Circle and that invokes `catkin run_tests` and then handles copying the test reports to where Circle can access them, but this only works for my C++ packages not for my Java ones. Once `gradle test` is invoked, I can handle putting the results where the ShadowRobot system expects them, but if it's never called there's not much I feel I can do. I'm not fully familiar with Catkin\CMake so I'm curious if I can just add the expected functionality to the CMakeLists.txt in my Java packages somehow without having to modify the whole rosjava Catkin plugin.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269945/rosjava-&-catkin_make-run_tests/) by [kyle.rush](https://answers.ros.org/users/31746/kyle.rush/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case anyone was curious, I ended up writing a python script to invoke the `gradlew test` command, modified my build.gradle to aggregate all the test result xmls into a top level folder, then the python script parses those and aggregates the test case output into a summarized test report and finally writes that test summary to the workspace's `build/test_results` folder.

I hooked this script into the `catkin_make run_tests` command via the `catkin_add_nosetest(...)` option in my Java project `CMakeLists.txt`. As far as Catkin knows, it's running a python test suite. I just happen to proxy my Java testing through there. It's hacky but it works for now.

---

Originally posted by [kyle.rush](https://answers.ros.org/users/31746/kyle.rush/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-11-03**:
I've never tried it in a project of my own, but rosjava_core has some tests in the "test" folder that are actually executed when the workspace is built with catkin_make if I am not mistaken.
Perhaps that structure can be replicated in your project too.